# Weird Ascii characters in output of decoding an Encoded image Java

Tags: java, image, encoding, steganography

I am writing a Image encryption program in which I encode a string inside the image.

I am working with `.png` images.

Encoding is performed by following steps:

- Pixels of the image are stored in a 2D array using getRGB().
- Each Character in the string is converted in to binary form and stored in an array.
- The LSB of every byte of the `4byte` pixel is changed according to every bit of the binary form of the character. LSB of first byte is at 0th position, LSB of second byte is at 8th position, third byte is at 16th position, and fourth byte is at 24th position.
- After encoding, the modified pixels are written into the original image by using setRGB() method.

For decoding:

- Read the pixels of the image using getRGB();
- The reverse method of encoding is applied for retreiving the data.
- After every 8th bit, int containing the decoded bits is converted in to character. Then initialized with zero for the other character.

  ```
              if((pixels[i][j] & change)==1)  
              {
                  tempText|=1 ;
              }

              tempText<<=1;
  ```

Where change is 1,256,65536,16777216 depending on the iteration. Whose 0th,8th,16th and 24th bits are one.

The code compiles fine. But after decoding, I get weird ascii characters in output. I couldn't find the reason for this. So I am consulting experts here.

Comment: Are you saving the image as JPEG?

Comment: This can only work on loss less compression formats (as PNG)

Comment: @Umer Farooq: what you're doing is called "steganography".  I added the tag accordingly.

Comment: @Umer Farooq: no problem... Btw in your ideone.com paste, you wrote "Stegnography".  It's really "Steganography" (you forgot an 'a')   ; )

Comment: For better help sooner, post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/).

Comment: Your problem most likely is that you don't load the image properly. In such a case, the alpha channel will default to 255 no matter its stored value. To test this, load your image, check the alpha channel of a few pixels and just change it to different numbers. They can be as wildly different as you want. Save the image and load it again. Is the alpha channel of the modified pixels what you had changed them to or do they hold different values now?

Answer (score 0):

*(this is too long for a comment)*

You wrote:

int change=0;

```
                            for(int k=0;k<4;k++)
                            {
                                    if(k==0)
                                    {
                                            change=1;
                                    }
                                    else
                                            if(k==1)
                                            {
                                                    change=256;
                                            }
                                            else
                                                    if(k==2)
                                                    {
                                                            change=65536;
                                                    }
                                                    else
                                                            if(k==3)
                                                            {
                                                                    change = 16777216;
                                                            }
```

And there's a lot of repetition in there.  Typically computers are very good at eliminating repetition.

This can be rewritten if I'm not miskaten by this one liner:

```
final int change = 1 << 8 * k;
```

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out . I know this code needs alot of tweaking but at the moment I trying to solve this weird output problem

Comment: Have you encountered any problem in this code which is causing this anomaly in the output